# how to monitor celery worker status, and restart after being dead?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I ran Celery with Django for some long background tasks. In some cases, the worker may die, for some reason I don't know yet. Before I find the root cause, I'd like to have a monitor/watchdog so the workers can be restarted after being found dead. 
What's the suggested approach for implementing this watchdog?

Answer (score 1):

To keep your workers alive you're looking for [Supervisor](http://thomassileo.com/blog/2012/08/20/how-to-keep-celery-running-with-supervisor/).

To monitor your tasks, you're looking for something like [Flower](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#flower-real-time-celery-web-monitor) (Warning! Amazon SQS [doesn't support monitoring](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/)).